# coburtura link with marathon

Tags: marathontesting

I am newbie in coburtura and marathon. I have few doubts regarding integration of coburtura with marathon. Using ant I tried to run the coburtura using the jar file which is used in marathon. cobutura.ser file is not updated when marathon automation testing completed. Kindly let me know how to connect .ser file into marathon?

Answer (score 0):

Marathon aborts the AUT, rather than exiting it. I suspect that is the issue with the 'ser' file not being written. One option is to include the exit actions in the script.